# How to draw rectangle on custom video widget t in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, paintevent

I want to select an area on a custom video widget and draw rectangle on selected area.

So far I can select an area with QRubberband but I am having trouble with drawing the rectangle after releasing left click.

Whenever I click-drag then release to draw rectangle it gives this error:

> QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter on backingstore paint device
>
> **The program has unexpectedly finished.**

Here is my code:

**myvideoobject.h**

```
#ifndef MYVIDEOOBJECT_H
#define MYVIDEOOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QRubberBand>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QRect>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class MyVideoObject : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyVideoObject(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev);

private:
    QRubberBand* rubberBand;
    QPainter* painter;
    //QRect *rectangle;

    QPoint origin;
    QPoint endPoint;

};

#endif // MYVIDEOOBJECT_H
```

**myvideoobject.cpp**

```
#include "myvideoobject.h"

MyVideoObject::MyVideoObject(QWidget* parent) :
QVideoWidget(parent)
{
    rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(0,0,50,50);//ileride silebilrisin

}

void MyVideoObject::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin,ev->pos()).normalized());
}

void MyVideoObject::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    origin = ev->pos();
    if(!rubberBand)
         rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin,QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();
}

void MyVideoObject::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    rubberBand->hide();

    endPoint = ev->pos();

    painter->begin(this);
    painter->drawRect(QRect(origin,endPoint));

}

void MyVideoObject::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{
    QRect rect = ev->rect();
    painter = new QPainter(this);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter->setPen(Qt::black);
    painter->drawText(rect,Qt::AlignCenter,"Data");
    painter->drawRect(rect);

//painter->setPen(Qt::red);
}
```

I didn't add mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h cuz there isn't much code in those other than selecting video with openfiledialog.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pointer: `QPainter *painter`, this can point to any memory since it has garbage. so when you do `painter->begin(this)` you are accessing uninitialized memory, that's why you get that error. On the other hand in a `QWidget` such as `QVideoWidget` should only be painted in the method `paintEvent`, the strategy is to have variables that save the state of what you want to paint, for example the `QRect`, and call update to paint it.

**myvideoobject.h**

```
#ifndef MYVIDEOOBJECT_H
#define MYVIDEOOBJECT_H

#include <QVideoWidget>

class QRubberBand;

class MyVideoObject : public QVideoWidget
{
public:
    MyVideoObject(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev);
private:
    QRubberBand *rubberBand;
    QPoint origin;
    QRect rect;
};

#endif // MYVIDEOOBJECT_H
```

**myvideoobject.cpp**

```
#include "myvideoobject.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QRubberBand>

MyVideoObject::MyVideoObject(QWidget *parent):
    QVideoWidget(parent),
    rubberBand(nullptr){}

void MyVideoObject::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    origin = ev->pos();
    if(!rubberBand)
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin,QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();
    QVideoWidget::mousePressEvent(ev);
}

void MyVideoObject::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin,ev->pos()).normalized());
    QVideoWidget::mouseMoveEvent(ev);
}

void MyVideoObject::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    rect = rubberBand->geometry();
    update();
    QVideoWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(ev);
}

void MyVideoObject::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{
    QVideoWidget::paintEvent(ev);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.save();
    painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
    if(!rect.isNull())
        painter.drawRect(rect);
    painter.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However even though this draws the rectangle with QRubberband. It doesnt draw the red rectangle I want. Also it now gives warning `QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called`

Comment: @onurcevik That warning: *QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called* is common, do not care about it, on the other hand QVideoWidget is a special widget so it seems that the general solution does not work, I'll have to use another method,

Comment: I also define `QMediaPlayer` and `MyVideoObject` as pointers in mainwindow.cpp could that be the source of problem ?

Comment: @onurcevik It has nothing to do with it, I have had similar problems and I have been able to solve them with a trick, I am implementing the solution, wait a moment.

Comment: hey its been 2 hours :) are you still trying to implement the solution? If not can you please tell me about that "trick" of yours so I can try to solve the problem by myself ?

Comment: @onurcevik When I have time I will upload my solution, I am busy without my pc.

Comment: @onurcevik, SO is not a helpdesk. Someone somewhere has taken his/her precious time to consider your problem and try to help you __for free__. Don’t take this for granted, show appreciation and don’t push it, even if it takes 2 hours or two months or forever.

Comment: @scopchanov I never said its a helpdesk. He said he'll help in couple mins but didn't so I thought he forgot. Now he told me that he is busy I'll wait for his solution patiently just like you said :) .

Comment: I tried the above solution but it doesn't invoke `paintEvent` when I release the mouse button, any ideas?

Comment: @Oshada If you have a problem then create a new question :-)